# Specification pattern vs Always valid domain model

Tags: c#, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, specification-pattern

Let's say we have two aggregates:

```
public class Order : IAggregateRoot
{
    public Address Address { get; private set; }
    
    public int? BuyerId {get; private set}

    public OrderStatus OrderStatus { get; private set; }

    public string Description {get; private set;}
}
```

and

```
public class Buyer : IAggregateRoot
{
    public string IdentityGuid { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<PaymentMethod> PaymentMethods => _paymentMethods.AsReadOnly();
    
    public bool IsActivated { get; private set; }
}
```

and we want to allow only activated user to create an order.
**Should this logic be inserted in domain service or in specification pattern like this (and how this will affect always valid domain model state):**

```
interface ISpecification {
    bool IsSatisfiedBy(Offer offer);
}
```

```
public class OrderSpecification : ISpecification {
    private Buyer _buyer;
    public OrderSpecification(Buyer buyer) =>
        _buyer = buyer;

    public bool IsSatisfiedBy(Order order) => buyer.IsActivated 
...
}
```

and then in order

```
    public Order(..., ISpecification spec) {
        // field initialize and then 

        if (!spec.IsSatisfiedBy(this))
            throw new OfferConstructionDomainException(...);
    }
```

Comment: From my understanding you are doing this absolutely right. Your domain needs to validate if it is in a consistant state. 
As long as the buyer is not activated your domain needs to throw a domain exception.

Comment: Suggest you also post this on the Software Engineering and/or Code Review SE sites. The question is likely to get closed as opinion-based here.